# Problema con las fuentes en CSS/HTML, no aparecen ni en la preview ni en la página aún habiendolas puesto

Tags: html, css, fuentes, google-fonts

Podeis ayudarme con este problema?

```
#CuadroCabecera {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1840px;
  height: 295px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  font: montserrat;
  font-size: 200px;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  /* IMPORTANTE */
  text-align: center;
  left: -4px;
}
```

Y este es el codigo HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap');
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <p id="CuadroCabecera"><strong>CyberSpace</strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Vale, el he escrito todo este codigo, pero, al iniciar la preview o directamente entrar en el guardado del html la fuente de Montserrat no me aparece aun habiendola instalado tanto en css como en html

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, ésta es la página en castellano. Por favor, usa el castellano para comunicarte con los demás. Cerraremos la pregunta si sigue redactada en inglés.

Comment: Ya esta, perdon.

Comment: Abre la consola del navegador y verifica algún posible mensaje de error que estés obteniendo

Comment: como abro la consola en dreamweaber

Comment: Hola @SershRX si alguna respuesta ayudo a solucionar el problema recuerda marcarla como solución, revisa [tour], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El `@import` debe ir en tu CSS y no en el `<style>`, ya que al ponerlo en el `<style>` lo estás importando únicamente para ese estilo, mas no universalmente.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Puedes vincular la fuente con `<link>`
- Cambiar tu archivo CSS

**Con la primera:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap" />
```

Importas globalmente la fuente de manera que la puedes usar en otros estilos

**Con la segunda**

Añade en la primera línea de tu CSS el `@import`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@800&display=swap');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco Google incluye dos `<link>` uno de ellos es un preconnect, además creo recordar que las fuentes van entre comillas `font-family: 'Montserrat';` (la primera con mayúscula).

Espero que te sirva para algo